# Query based on boolean value of another table

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a TABLE called *Employees* and another called *Wages*

#### Employees columns

- FirstName
- LastName
- SSN (social security number)
- Retired (true/false)

#### Wages columns

- Time
- AmountPaid (they can still be paid even if they are retired)
- SSN (social security number)

#### How can I Query *Wages* so that it returns:

- The Time, AmountPaid, SSN of all retired Employees
- The Time, AmountPaid, SSN, FirstName, LastName of all retired Employees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Wages.Time, Wages.AmountPaid, Wages.SSN, 
       Employees.FirstName, Employees.LastName 
FROM Wages, Employees 
WHERE Wages.SSN == Employees.SSN AND Employees.Retired == true;
```